# How do I style the automatically-generated unsubscribe / manage preferences link from Sendgrid?

Tags: python, css, sendgrid

If I enable subscription tracking in Sendgrid, Sendgrid will automatically generate and append a couple links to my email (unsubscribe from the list and manage email preferences, as seen [here](https://sendgrid.com/blog/advanced-suppression-manager-a-developers-example/) in step 7), but the links are left-aligned and don't match the font style of my email. How do I style those links?

I'd be fine with just centering those links, but I'd prefer to do a few different things.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using SendGrid's **Unsubscribe Group**, adding the tag `<% asm_group_unsubscribe_url %>` or `<% asm_group_unsubscribe_raw_url %>` in the email content will solve the problem.

1. `<%asm_group_unsubscribe_url%>` will add the default text in the link "Unsubscribe from this list"
2. `<%asm_group_unsubscribe_raw_url%>` will give you a raw URL which you  can use as the `href`in the anchor tag.

Refer: [Group Unsubscribers](https://sendgrid.com/docs/User_Guide/Suppressions/group_unsubscribes.html)

Comment: Of several similar questions, this is the only solution I found that a) actually answered the question and b) was specific to group unsubscribes rather than subscription tracking. I _did_ have to remove the spaces in the tags for it to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<% Unsubscribe Here %>` to specify where the unsubscribe part should be there.

Otherwise, they will put it automatically. https://sendgrid.com/docs/User_Guide/Settings/tracking.html